# RDP Smart Card Redirect

Tags: 20.04, windows, remote-desktop, rdp, smartcard

I'm trying to get my smart card passed through RDP from Ubuntu to a Windows box. It didn't work in the beginning, randomly worked for a couple of logins, and then never worked again (no changes made). I'm down for trying whatever software can accomplish it on Ubuntu, but I've been trying FreeRDP and Remmina which is just a wrapper of FreeRDP. When it worked, a virtual smart card reader was listed under Windows Device Manager, when it doesn't work, there is no smart reader listed. Everything works in the RDP session other than the Smart Card.

Problem

Smart Card Redirect from Ubuntu to Windows using FreeRDP/Remmina

Specs

Ubuntu 20.04.1

Windows 10.0.19042 Build 19042 (have tried multiple versions of Windows 10)

FreeRDP version 2.2.0 from Ubuntu repos

SCM Microsystems Inc. SCR 3310 card reader

Command and Error Messages

`xfreerdp /u:<user> /v:<ip> /smartcard /p:password`

```
[17:35:08:824] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state

[17:35:08:824] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpdr

[17:35:08:824] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpsnd

[17:35:08:824] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr

[17:35:09:138] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.primitives] - primitives autodetect, using optimized

[17:35:09:139] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_tcp_is_hostname_resolvable:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state

[17:35:09:139] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_tcp_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state

[17:35:09:148] [52329:52330] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - Certificate verification failure 'unable to get local issuer certificate (20)' at stack position 0

[17:35:09:148] [52329:52330] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - CN = <computer-name>

[17:35:10:349] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.gdi] - Local framebuffer format PIXEL_FORMAT_BGRX32

[17:35:10:349] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.gdi] - Remote framebuffer format PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB16

[17:35:10:366] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.winpr.clipboard] - initialized POSIX local file subsystem

[17:35:10:366] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.channels.rdpsnd.client] - [static] Loaded fake backend for rdpsnd

[17:35:10:366] [52329:52344] [INFO][com.freerdp.channels.rdpdr.client] - Loading device service smartcard (static)

[17:35:10:370] [52329:52344] [INFO][com.freerdp.channels.rdpdr.client] - registered device #1: SCARD (type=32 id=1)

[17:35:10:709] [52329:52330] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - rdp_set_error_info:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state

[17:35:12:219] [52329:52344] [INFO][com.freerdp.channels.rdpdr.client] - registered device #1: SCARD (type=32 id=1)

[17:35:12:227] [52329:52344] [INFO][com.freerdp.channels.rdpdr.client] - registered device #1: SCARD (type=32 id=1)

[17:35:12:463] [52329:52381] [ERROR][com.freerdp.channels.smartcard.client] - SCardGetDeviceTypeIdW failed with error SCARD_E_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE [-2146435038]

[17:35:12:463] [52329:52381] [WARN][com.freerdp.channels.smartcard.client] - IRP failure: SCardGetDeviceTypeId (0x00090108), status: SCARD_E_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE (0x80100022)

[17:35:12:466] [52329:52383] [ERROR][com.freerdp.channels.smartcard.client] - SCardGetDeviceTypeIdW failed with error SCARD_E_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE [-2146435038]

[17:35:12:466] [52329:52383] [WARN][com.freerdp.channels.smartcard.client] - IRP failure: SCardGetDeviceTypeId (0x00090108), status: SCARD_E_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE (0x80100022)

[17:35:12:470] [52329:52385] [ERROR][com.freerdp.channels.smartcard.client] - SCardGetDeviceTypeIdW failed with error SCARD_E_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE [-2146435038]

[17:35:12:470] [52329:52385] [WARN][com.freerdp.channels.smartcard.client] - IRP failure: SCardGetDeviceTypeId (0x00090108), status: SCARD_E_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE (0x80100022)
```

`pcsc_scan` Output

```
Using reader plug'n play mechanism

Scanning present readers...

0: SCM Microsystems Inc. SCR 3310 [CCID Interface] (xxxx) 00 00

Wed Dec 30 17:36:18 2020

Reader 0: SCM Microsystems Inc. SCR 3310 [CCID Interface] (asdf) 00 00

Event number: 0

Card state: Card inserted,

ATR: asdf



ATR: asdf

+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention

+ T0 = F9, Y(1): 1111, K: 9 (historical bytes)

TA(1) = 18 --> Fi=372, Di=12, 31 cycles/ETU

129032 bits/s at 4 MHz, fMax for Fi = 5 MHz => 161290 bits/s

TB(1) = 00 --> VPP is not electrically connected

TC(1) = 00 --> Extra guard time: 0

TD(1) = 00 --> Y(i+1) = 0000, Protocol T = 0

-----

+ Historical bytes: asdf

Category indicator byte: 53 (proprietary format)



Possibly identified card (using /home/<user>/.cache/smartcard_list.txt):

xxxx

G+D FIPS 201 SCE 7.0 (PKI)
```